# Django, switching views basing on the request

Tags: django, authentication, django-generic-views

I want to display different thing at the **same** URL (home page) depending on whether a user is logged in or not.

So, if he is **not** authenticated I'll display a page which does not involve any DB query, otherwise, if he **is** logged in, I'll display his projects (this involves DB access).

So, how can I accomplish this, given that:

- I have only 1 url pattern
- I want to use class based generic views (specifically, TemplateView in one case, DetailView in the other).

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if User.is_authenticated(), if they are, query for the projects, if not don't query for the projects, and in the view see if the projects variable is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally one would use the [Login Required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator but since you only have a single URL you could check whether request.user.is_authenticated() is True. If it's True return the template corresponding to the logged in user, otherwise return the other one.

Class Based Views

Take a look at this: [login required in TemplateView](http://www.gregaker.net/2012/apr/19/how-do-django-class-based-views-work/)

It used the dispatch method to check for a user being authenticated in a class based view.

from django import http
from django.views import generic

```
class AboutView(generic.TemplateView):
    """ About page view. """
    template_name = 'about.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise http.Http404
        return super(AboutView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(AboutView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['something_else'] = None  # add something to ctx
        return ctx
```

Comment: Yes, I would know how to do this with a function-based view, but what about class based views? Do you think in this case it's an overkill?